# Discord bot that reacts to its own message

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

I got problems with my current discord.js code. I'm trying to make a bot that will remind me every hour to do something, but if I don't do that I want it to add 1hour ( so basically if I don't do it for 4 hours I want the message to say: It's been 4 Hour since last buffer check, etc.). Also when I wanted to add reactions the bot started to react to every message in that certain channel, but I want it to react to its own message so then I could add more stuff. When I launch it, it works but spams. The code might be ugly and complicated and I'm sorry about that.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const Buffer = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#FF4C26')
    .setTitle("**It's time to check buffers!**")
    .setDescription("**It's been **" + "`" + lastbuffer + " Hour" + "`" + "** since last buffercheck, <@&675688526460878848>**." + " **Check now!**")
    .setThumbnail('https://art.pixilart.com/88534e2f28b65a4.png')
    .setFooter('WEEEEEWOOOOO')
    .setTimestamp();
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}bstart`));
    let role2 = message.guild.roles.cache.get("675688526460878848")
    client.channels.cache.get("<700296799482675230>")
})
client.on('message', message => {
    message.channel.send(Buffer)
    message.react('✅')
    message.react('')
})

client.login(token);
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: You are lacking focus on this question, it looks like you are trying to cram multiple questions into the single question and that is confusing as to what you actually want to do.  The StackOverflow format is question and answer, you need to be very specific to the problem.

Comment: so you're suggesting me to ask1 question and then when I get an answer ask another one in another post?

Comment: That is correct.  Better to ask two focused questions than one confusing one.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```js
setInterval(function(){
    client.channels.cache.get("CHANNEL_ID").send(Buffer).then(msg => {
        msg.react('✅');
        msg.react('');
    });
}, 3600000); // waits for 1 hour
```

You can also use `client.users.cache.get("USER_ID").send()` to send via DMs. [This](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#await-reactions) also might be useful for responding the user when they click on a reaction.

Comment: I did what you said andddd now I'm getting 2 messages at once ;/

Comment: Fixed the multiple message problem. I forgot to add {} after if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}bstart`));